# How to display the selected option of a <select> in HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display the selected option from a  element using HTML I created in JavaScript. The select element has three options: "On the day", "Before", and "After".
[image: Adding Reminder]
What should happen next is that after clicking the Add button on the bottom-right, the selected option (e.g., "Before") should appear in the "When" column of the reminder list.
[image: "When" column shouldn't be blank]
In the JavaScript file, I have a function called changeInnerHTML(sel) that should change the innerHTML of that column to that selected option. However, each time I click on one of the options, this error appears in the browser console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at changeInnerHTML (Create Event.js:195:54)`.
Here is the entire JS file:

```js
var br = document.createElement("br");

function create_reminder() {
  let form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "post");
  form.setAttribute("action", "");
  form.setAttribute("id", "reminder_form");

  // When
  let reminder_status_label = document.createElement("label");
  reminder_status_label.setAttribute("for", "reminder_status");
  reminder_status_label.innerHTML = "When";

  let reminder_status = document.createElement("select");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("name", "reminder_status");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("id", "reminder-status-sel");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("onChange", "setReminderWhen(this);changeInnerHTML(this);");

  let reminder_status_1 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_1.setAttribute("value", "on-the-day");
  reminder_status_1.innerHTML = "On the day";

  let reminder_status_2 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_2.setAttribute("value", "before");
  reminder_status_2.innerHTML = "Before";

  let reminder_status_3 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_3.setAttribute("value", "After");
  reminder_status_3.innerHTML = "After";

  // Note
  let note_label = document.createElement("label");
  note_label.setAttribute("for", "note");
  note_label.innerHTML = "Note";

  let note = document.createElement("textarea");
  note.setAttribute("name", "note");
  note.setAttribute("id", "reminder-note");
  note.setAttribute("row", "10");
  note.setAttribute("col", "60");

  // Send to
  let send_to_label = document.createElement("label");
  send_to_label.setAttribute("for", "send-to");
  send_to_label.innerHTML = "Send to";

  let send_to = document.createElement("select");
  send_to.setAttribute("name", "send-to");
  send_to.setAttribute("onChange", "setReminderWhen(this);");

  let blank = document.createElement("option");
  blank.setAttribute("value", "--");

  let email_1 = document.createElement("option");
  email_1.setAttribute("value", "naa1234@cohousing.site");
  email_1.innerHTML = "naa1234@cohousing.site";

  let email_2 = document.createElement("option");
  email_2.setAttribute("value", "sd4567@cohousing.site");
  email_2.innerHTML = "sd4567@cohousing.site";

  let email_3 = document.createElement("option");
  email_3.setAttribute("value", "mk7890@cohousing.site");
  email_3.innerHTML = "mk7890@cohousing.site";

  let email_4 = document.createElement("option");
  email_4.setAttribute("value", "jk0123@cohousing.site");
  email_4.innerHTML = "jk0123@cohousing.site";

  let email_5 = document.createElement("option");
  email_5.setAttribute("value", "ms3456@cohousing.site");
  email_5.innerHTML = "ms3456@cohousing.site";

  let add_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "add_reminder");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "add-reminder-to-list-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Add";
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML='1 reminder';list_reminder();");

  let cancel_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "cancel_reminder");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "cancel-reminder-to-list-btn");
  cancel_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Cancel";
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('reminder_form').style.visibility='hidden'");

  // Form
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(reminder_status_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(reminder_status);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_1);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_2);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_3);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(note_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(note);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(send_to_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(send_to);
  send_to.appendChild(blank);
  send_to.appendChild(email_1);
  send_to.appendChild(email_2);
  send_to.appendChild(email_3);
  send_to.appendChild(email_4);
  send_to.appendChild(email_5);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(add_reminder_btn);
  form.appendChild(cancel_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(form);

}

function list_reminder() {
  let add_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "add_reminder");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "add-reminder-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Add";
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML='1 reminder';list_reminder();");

  let reminder_table = document.createElement("table");
  reminder_table.setAttribute("id", "reminder-table");
  let reminder_table_head = document.createElement("thead");
  reminder_table_head.setAttribute("id", "reminder-list-header");
  let reminder_table_col_1 = document.createElement("th");
  reminder_table_col_1.innerHTML = "Send to";
  let reminder_table_col_2 = document.createElement("th");
  reminder_table_col_2.innerHTML = "When";
  let reminder_table_col_3 = document.createElement("th");

  let reminder_table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
  let reminder_table_row = document.createElement("tr");
  let reminder_table_cell_1 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_1.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");
  let reminder_table_cell_2 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_2.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");
  reminder_table_cell_2.setAttribute("id", "reminder-when");
  let reminder_table_cell_3 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_3.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");

  reminder_table_cell_1.innerHTML = "abc1234@cohousing.site";
  // reminder_table_cell_2.innerHTML = "";

  let edit_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "edit_reminder");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "edit-delete-reminder-btns");
  edit_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Edit";

  let delete_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "delete_reminder");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "edit-delete-reminder-btns");
  delete_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Delete";

  reminder_table.appendChild(reminder_table_head);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_1);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_2);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_3);

  reminder_table.appendChild(reminder_table_body);
  reminder_table_body.appendChild(reminder_table_row);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_1);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_2);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_3);
  reminder_table_cell_3.appendChild(edit_reminder_btn);
  reminder_table_cell_3.appendChild(delete_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(add_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(reminder_table);
}

// Used to ensure that values are being read
function setReminderWhen(sel) {
  alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
}

function changeInnerHTML(sel) {
  document.getElementById('reminder-when').innerHTML = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

And here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

body, input, select, option, textarea {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #666666;
}

input, select, textarea {
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

input, select, option {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

textarea {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%
}

#guest-room-address {
  width: 30%;
}

#reminder {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px #e8e8e8 solid;
  padding: 10px 0px 60px 10px;
}

.add-reminder-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#add-reservation-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #363636;
  border: 15px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cancel-reservation-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 15px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cancel-reservation-btn a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cancel-reservation-btn a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cancel-add-btns {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#reminder-list-header {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

td.reminder-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 10%;
}

.edit-delete-reminder-btns {
  border: 3px solid #363636;
  background: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 20px;
}

.edit-delete-reminder-btns:hover {
  background: #363636;
  color: white;
}

#add-reminder-to-list-btn {
  border: 1px solid #363636;
  background: #363636;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}

#cancel-reminder-to-list-btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}

#reminder-note {
  width: 98%;
}

#reminder-table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Add Event to Main Calendar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" width="device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Create Event.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Create Event.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>
      <h1>Add Reservation to Guest Room Calendar</h1>
      <hr>

      <form action="SMTWTFS Control Page 1.html" method="post">
        <label for="check-in-date">Check-in Date</label>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="check-in-date" min="2022-05-18" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="check-in-time">Check-in Time</label>
        <br>
        <select name="hour" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>

        <select name="minute" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="00">00</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="35">35</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="55">55</option>
        </select>

        <select name="am-pm" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="am">AM</option>
          <option value="pm">PM</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="check-out-date">Check-out Date</label>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="check-out-date" min="2022-05-18" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="check-out-time">Check-out Time</label>
        <br>
        <select name="hour" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>

        <select name="minute" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="00">00</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="35">35</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="55">55</option>
        </select>

        <select name="am-pm" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="am">AM</option>
          <option value="pm">PM</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="guest-room-address">Guest Room Address</label>
        <br>
        <input id="guest-room-address" type="text" name="guest-room-address" value="" placeholder="1234 A St, Anytown, XY 12345" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="reserved-by">Reserved by</label>
        <br>
        <select name="reserved-by" required>
          <option value="nivaldo-acevedo">Nivaldo Acevedo</option>
          <option value="sean-davey">Sean Davey</option>
          <option value="margo-ketchum">Margo Ketchum</option>
          <option value="jeff-kosky">Jeff Kosky</option>
          <option value="mary-selman">Mary Selman</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="no-of-guests">No. of Guests</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="no-of-guests" min="1" max="5" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="hosted-by">Hosted by</label>
        <br>
        <select name="hosted-by" required>
          <option value="nivaldo-acevedo">Nivaldo Acevedo</option>
          <option value="sean-davey">Sean Davey</option>
          <option value="margo-ketchum">Margo Ketchum</option>
          <option value="jeff-kosky">Jeff Kosky</option>
          <option value="mary-selman">Mary Selman</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="notes">Notes</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="notes" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>

        <div id="reminder">
          0 reminders <button type="button" name="add-reminder" class="add-reminder-btn" id="add-reminder-btn" onclick="create_reminder()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cancel-add-btns">
      <button type="submit" name="add-reservation" id="add-reservation-btn">ADD</button>
      <button type="button" name="cancel-reservation" id="cancel-reservation-btn"> <a href="SMTWTFS Control Page 1.html">Cancel</a></button>
    </div>

    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

I've placed this function inside of the onChange attribute of reminder_status (line 17). I have also tried onClick, but it generated the same result. I have also tried to using this code: `document.getElementById('reminder-when').innerHTML = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;` within the list_reminder() function but to no avail. I'm not sure what else I can do. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: The table you're trying to write to isn't there when the select list is changed. To see what I mean add `list_reminder();` before `changeInnerHTML(this);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bloodyKnuckles told you; the element you're trying to get isn't present in the DOM when the domument is loaded that's why you cannot get access to it.

I don't know if this is an elegant way to solve your issue but at least you'll understand where the problem is. What you can do is make the `select` save its value in a global variable, I made some comments to your code.

```js
      var br = document.createElement("br");
var option="";/*---added----*/
function create_reminder() {
  let form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "post");
  form.setAttribute("action", "");
  form.setAttribute("id", "reminder_form");

  // When
  let reminder_status_label = document.createElement("label");
  reminder_status_label.setAttribute("for", "reminder_status");
  reminder_status_label.innerHTML = "When";

  let reminder_status = document.createElement("select");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("name", "reminder_status");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("id", "reminder-status-sel");
  //reminder_status.setAttribute("onChange", "setReminderWhen(this);changeInnerHTML(this);");
  reminder_status.setAttribute("onChange", "setReminderWhen(this);");/*---added----*/
  let reminder_status_1 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_1.setAttribute("value", "on-the-day");
  reminder_status_1.innerHTML = "On the day";

  let reminder_status_2 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_2.setAttribute("value", "before");
  reminder_status_2.innerHTML = "Before";

  let reminder_status_3 = document.createElement("option");
  reminder_status_3.setAttribute("value", "After");
  reminder_status_3.innerHTML = "After";

  // Note
  let note_label = document.createElement("label");
  note_label.setAttribute("for", "note");
  note_label.innerHTML = "Note";

  let note = document.createElement("textarea");
  note.setAttribute("name", "note");
  note.setAttribute("id", "reminder-note");
  note.setAttribute("row", "10");
  note.setAttribute("col", "60");

  // Send to
  let send_to_label = document.createElement("label");
  send_to_label.setAttribute("for", "send-to");
  send_to_label.innerHTML = "Send to";

  let send_to = document.createElement("select");
  send_to.setAttribute("name", "send-to");
  send_to.setAttribute("onChange", "setReminderWhen(this);");

  let blank = document.createElement("option");
  blank.setAttribute("value", "--");

  let email_1 = document.createElement("option");
  email_1.setAttribute("value", "naa1234@cohousing.site");
  email_1.innerHTML = "naa1234@cohousing.site";

  let email_2 = document.createElement("option");
  email_2.setAttribute("value", "sd4567@cohousing.site");
  email_2.innerHTML = "sd4567@cohousing.site";

  let email_3 = document.createElement("option");
  email_3.setAttribute("value", "mk7890@cohousing.site");
  email_3.innerHTML = "mk7890@cohousing.site";

  let email_4 = document.createElement("option");
  email_4.setAttribute("value", "jk0123@cohousing.site");
  email_4.innerHTML = "jk0123@cohousing.site";

  let email_5 = document.createElement("option");
  email_5.setAttribute("value", "ms3456@cohousing.site");
  email_5.innerHTML = "ms3456@cohousing.site";

  let add_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "add_reminder");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "add-reminder-to-list-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Add";
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML='1 reminder';list_reminder();");

  let cancel_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "cancel_reminder");
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("id", "cancel-reminder-to-list-btn");
  cancel_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Cancel";
  cancel_reminder_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('reminder_form').style.visibility='hidden'");

  // Form
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(reminder_status_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(reminder_status);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_1);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_2);
  reminder_status.appendChild(reminder_status_3);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(note_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(note);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(send_to_label);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
  form.appendChild(send_to);
  send_to.appendChild(blank);
  send_to.appendChild(email_1);
  send_to.appendChild(email_2);
  send_to.appendChild(email_3);
  send_to.appendChild(email_4);
  send_to.appendChild(email_5);
  form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

  form.appendChild(add_reminder_btn);
  form.appendChild(cancel_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(form);

}

function list_reminder() {
  let add_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "add_reminder");
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "add-reminder-btn");
  add_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Add";
  add_reminder_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML='1 reminder';list_reminder();");

  let reminder_table = document.createElement("table");
  reminder_table.setAttribute("id", "reminder-table");
  let reminder_table_head = document.createElement("thead");
  reminder_table_head.setAttribute("id", "reminder-list-header");
  let reminder_table_col_1 = document.createElement("th");
  reminder_table_col_1.innerHTML = "Send to";
  let reminder_table_col_2 = document.createElement("th");
  reminder_table_col_2.innerHTML = "When";
  let reminder_table_col_3 = document.createElement("th");

  let reminder_table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
  let reminder_table_row = document.createElement("tr");
  let reminder_table_cell_1 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_1.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");
  let reminder_table_cell_2 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_2.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");
  reminder_table_cell_2.setAttribute("id", "reminder-when");
  reminder_table_cell_2.innerHTML = option;/*---added----*/
  let reminder_table_cell_3 = document.createElement("td");
  reminder_table_cell_3.setAttribute("class", "reminder-list");

  reminder_table_cell_1.innerHTML = "abc1234@cohousing.site";
  // reminder_table_cell_2.innerHTML = "";

  let edit_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "edit_reminder");
  edit_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "edit-delete-reminder-btns");
  edit_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Edit";

  let delete_reminder_btn = document.createElement("button");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("name", "delete_reminder");
  delete_reminder_btn.setAttribute("class", "edit-delete-reminder-btns");
  delete_reminder_btn.innerHTML = "Delete";

  reminder_table.appendChild(reminder_table_head);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_1);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_2);
  reminder_table_head.appendChild(reminder_table_col_3);

  reminder_table.appendChild(reminder_table_body);
  reminder_table_body.appendChild(reminder_table_row);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_1);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_2);
  reminder_table_row.appendChild(reminder_table_cell_3);
  reminder_table_cell_3.appendChild(edit_reminder_btn);
  reminder_table_cell_3.appendChild(delete_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(add_reminder_btn);

  document.getElementById("reminder")
    .appendChild(reminder_table);
}

// Used to ensure that values are being read
 function setReminderWhen(sel) {
  //alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
  option=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
/*
function changeInnerHTML(sel) {
  document.getElementById('reminder-when').innerHTML = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
} */
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

body, input, select, option, textarea {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: #666666;
}

input, select, textarea {
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

input, select, option {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

textarea {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%
}

#guest-room-address {
  width: 30%;
}

#reminder {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 3px #e8e8e8 solid;
  padding: 10px 0px 60px 10px;
}

.add-reminder-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#add-reservation-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #363636;
  border: 15px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cancel-reservation-btn {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 15px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cancel-reservation-btn a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cancel-reservation-btn a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cancel-add-btns {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#reminder-list-header {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

td.reminder-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  width: 10%;
}

.edit-delete-reminder-btns {
  border: 3px solid #363636;
  background: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 20px;
}

.edit-delete-reminder-btns:hover {
  background: #363636;
  color: white;
}

#add-reminder-to-list-btn {
  border: 1px solid #363636;
  background: #363636;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}

#cancel-reminder-to-list-btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}

#reminder-note {
  width: 98%;
}

#reminder-table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Add Event to Main Calendar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" width="device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Create Event.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Create Event.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div>
      <h1>Add Reservation to Guest Room Calendar</h1>
      <hr>

      <form action="SMTWTFS Control Page 1.html" method="post">
        <label for="check-in-date">Check-in Date</label>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="check-in-date" min="2022-05-18" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="check-in-time">Check-in Time</label>
        <br>
        <select name="hour" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>

        <select name="minute" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="00">00</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="35">35</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="55">55</option>
        </select>

        <select name="am-pm" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="am">AM</option>
          <option value="pm">PM</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="check-out-date">Check-out Date</label>
        <br>
        <input type="date" name="check-out-date" min="2022-05-18" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="check-out-time">Check-out Time</label>
        <br>
        <select name="hour" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>

        <select name="minute" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="00">00</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="35">35</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="55">55</option>
        </select>

        <select name="am-pm" required>
          <option value="--"></option>
          <option value="am">AM</option>
          <option value="pm">PM</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="guest-room-address">Guest Room Address</label>
        <br>
        <input id="guest-room-address" type="text" name="guest-room-address" value="" placeholder="1234 A St, Anytown, XY 12345" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="reserved-by">Reserved by</label>
        <br>
        <select name="reserved-by" required>
          <option value="nivaldo-acevedo">Nivaldo Acevedo</option>
          <option value="sean-davey">Sean Davey</option>
          <option value="margo-ketchum">Margo Ketchum</option>
          <option value="jeff-kosky">Jeff Kosky</option>
          <option value="mary-selman">Mary Selman</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="no-of-guests">No. of Guests</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="no-of-guests" min="1" max="5" required>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="hosted-by">Hosted by</label>
        <br>
        <select name="hosted-by" required>
          <option value="nivaldo-acevedo">Nivaldo Acevedo</option>
          <option value="sean-davey">Sean Davey</option>
          <option value="margo-ketchum">Margo Ketchum</option>
          <option value="jeff-kosky">Jeff Kosky</option>
          <option value="mary-selman">Mary Selman</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="notes">Notes</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="notes" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>

        <div id="reminder">
          0 reminders <button type="button" name="add-reminder" class="add-reminder-btn" id="add-reminder-btn" onclick="create_reminder()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cancel-add-btns">
      <button type="submit" name="add-reservation" id="add-reservation-btn">ADD</button>
      <button type="button" name="cancel-reservation" id="cancel-reservation-btn"> <a href="SMTWTFS Control Page 1.html">Cancel</a></button>
    </div>

    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Generally want to avoid creating multiple global variables. Could this be accomplished by wrapping the code changes in an IIFE and adding ```addEventListener``` code within it to replace the ```onclick``` attributes in HTML. If there is nowhere else the functions need to be called that would be closer to best practices.

Comment: I tried adding an IIFE and addEventListener methods in my program, but it still doesn't display the selected option. Here's the revised code on PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/sk1xNNYJ